# DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable

Tags: macos, bash, shell, curl, sudo

When I use the following command in my Mac terminal:

```bash
sudo curl https://raw.github.com/gerrywastaken/git-new-workdir/master/git-new-workdir \
-o /usr/bin/git-new-workdir
```

It show this result:

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid

Password:

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0curl: (35) 

error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: which version of mac OS?

Comment: Version 10.8.4  Mountain lion

Answer (score 1):

Some work arround i found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4143805?start=30&tstart=0)

in your `.profile/.bashrc/.bash_profile` (depends on you terminal setting):

```
# set DYLD_* for my normal programs
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='..'

# set an alternative sudo
thesudo()
{
# back up the DYLD_* variables
local BACK=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

# unset DYLD_*
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

# calling sudo
/usr/bin/sudo "$@"

# restore DYLD_* after sudo finished
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BACK
}

# redirect sudo
alias sudo=thesudo
```

Comment: I add the above command in my .bash_profile but the same error again comming. ---------But when i add this command in my.bash_profile

Comment: When i add the following command in my .bash_profile----------

Comment: I add the above command in my .bash_profile but the same error     again comming. ---------But when i add this command in my.bash_profile -------sudo () { ( unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH; exec command sudo $* ) } then source it and 'sudo curl http' instread of 'https 'the error is not comming.